# CSS Specificity

Tags: css, stylesheet

Assuming this mark-up:

```
<html class="fr">
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="class1">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Will this:

```
.fr .class1 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

take precedence over this:

```
.class1 {
  background-color: red;
};
```

Edit:

To those wondering, yes I had tried :) I didn't explain the full problem here and discovered the issue after this post.

Basically, I had two styles in the same stylesheet:

```
.fr .class1 {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.class1 {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

While technically `.fr .class1` takes **precendence** over `.class1`, this doesn't mean the element replaces all of `.class1`'s styles with `.fr .class1`'s styles. Instead, it looks at `.fr .class1` for styles first, then `.class1`. This is "obvious" but this was why I was running into difficulty.

My goal was to remove styles by using `.fr .class1`'s precedence over `.class1`. In order to do this, I realized I need to set values to 0 or neutral values:

Example)

```
.fr .class1 {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 0;
  height: auto;
}
```

Otherwise, it will cascade to `.class1` and fill these styles in.

Comment: have you tried? best to try first...!

Comment: @Cubed: But given the history of browser bugs it is best to check the standard and then try it to make sure the browsers you care about follow the standard in the ways you need them to.

Comment: Added commentary in an edit to the original post.

Comment: As you've found out, CSS applies styles for each property independently, so sometimes re-setting the original value is neccessary. To facilitate this, CSS3 introduced the `initial` keyword.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, since `.fr .class1` references two class names and `.class1` only references one, the first is more specific. The rules in the CSS standard are [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity).

Answer (score 1):

Yes because the first example has **two** class names compared to **one**.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/yQvAF/

Try using this CSS specificity calculator: http://www.suzyit.com/tools/specificity.php

Answer (score 1):

In response to the edit:

CSS applies the values to each property individually. Block grouping does not matter. So

```
.fr .class1 {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.class1 {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

is the same as

```
.fr .class1 {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.class1 {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.class1 {
  line-height: 18px;
}
.class1 {
  height: 80px;
}
```

which, as `.fr .class1` is more specific than `.class1` alone, is the same as

```
.fr .class1 {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.class1 {
  line-height: 18px;
}
.class1 {
  height: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Precisely what I eventually discovered. Thanks for outlining this so clearly!